# Emphasize the part of a word that is not given

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the code:

```
var word = 'thisistheword';
var string = 'istheword';
console.log(word.replace(new RegExp(string, "gi"), "<b>"+string+"</b>"));
```

And now I get `this<b>istheword</b>`, but I want to receive inverted result, so: `<b>this</b>istheword`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var word = 'thisistheword';
var string = 'istheword';
console.log(word.replace(new RegExp("(.*)" + string , "gi"), "<b>$1</b>" + string));
```

gives: `<b>this</b>istheword`

`"(.*)" + string` means match everything preceding `string`.
Wrapped in `()` so that you can refer to it later with the `$1`

Comment: Nice, can it be done not only for the prefix, but too with suffix. So for example with "isthword" and "isthewordTHIS"?

Comment: you could do `word.replace(new RegExp("(.*)" + string + "(.*)", "gi"), "<b>$1</b>" + string + "<b>$2</b>")` but it will give you an empty `<b></b>` if there's no text either before/after `string`